# How to change the border color of a polygon based on an attribute value in R tmap

Tags: r, gis, tmap, tigris

I am trying to create a map using R's tmap package that has a different color outline for each value of an attribute. When filling the polygons, for example, I can simply do tm_polygons(col = "variable") to get a map that fills the polygons based on the "variable" attribute. I wish to do a similar thing, but with just the border, not the fill. I'm not finding any good answers, so I was hoping to get some help here!

Here is an example that illustrates the idea:

```
library(tigris)
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)

region_2 = states() %>% filter(REGION == 2)
states_of_interest = region_2 %>% filter(NAME %in% c("Ohio", "Missouri", "Wisconsin"))

tm_shape(region_2) + tm_polygons(col = "white") + tm_shape(states_of_interest) + .......
```

and I am not quite sure how to proceed

Basically, I want the borders of Ohio, Missouri, and Wisconsin to have a different color to distinguish them from one another, using the NAME attribute in `states_of_interest`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A potential workaround is to convert your `POLYGONS` to `LINESTRING` and proceed with `tm_lines()`:

```r
library(tigris)
#> To enable caching of data, set `options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)`
#> in your R script or .Rprofile.
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)

region_2 = states() %>% filter(REGION == 2)
#> Retrieving data for the year 2020
#>   |                                                                              |                                                                      |   0%  |                                                                              |                                                                      |   1%  |                                                                              |=                                                                     |   1%  |                                                                              |=                                                                     |   2%  |                                                                              |==                                                                    |   2%  |                                                                              |==                                                                    |   3%  |                                                                              |==                                                                    |   4%  |                                                                              |===                                                                   |   4%  |                                                                              |===                                                                   |   5%  |                                                                              |====                                                                  |   5%  |                                                                              |====                                                                  |   6%  |                                                                              |=====                                                                 |   6%  |                                                                              |=====                                                                 |   7%  |                                                                              |=====                                                                 |   8%  |                                                                              |======                                                                |   8%  |                                                                              |======                                                                |   9%  |                                                                              |=======                                                               |   9%  |                                                                              |=======                                                               |  10%  |                                                                              |=======                                                               |  11%  |                                                                              |========                                                              |  11%  |                                                                              |========                                                              |  12%  |                                                                              |=========                                                             |  12%  |                                                                              |=========                                                             |  13%  |                                                                              |=========                                                             |  14%  |                                                                              |==========                                                            |  14%  |                                                                              |==========                                                            |  15%  |                                                                              |===========                                                           |  15%  |                                                                              |===========                                                           |  16%  |                                                                              |============                                                          |  17%  |                                                                              |============                                                          |  18%  |                                                                              |=============                                                         |  18%  |                                                                              |=============                                                         |  19%  |                                                                              |==============                                                        |  19%  |                                                                              |==============                                                        |  20%  |                                                                              |==============                                                        |  21%  |                                                                              |===============                                                       |  21%  |                                                                              |===============                                                       |  22%  |                                                                              |================                                                      |  22%  |                                                                              |================                                                      |  23%  |                                                                              |=================                                                     |  24%  |                                                                              |=================                                                     |  25%  |                                                                              |==================                                                    |  25%  |                                                                              |==================                                                    |  26%  |                                                                              |===================                                                   |  27%  |                                                                              |====================                                                  |  28%  |                                                                              |====================                                                  |  29%  |                                                                              |=====================                                                 |  30%  |                                                                              |=====================                                                 |  31%  |                                                                              |======================                                                |  31%  |                                                                              |======================                                                |  32%  |                                                                              |=======================                                               |  32%  |                                                                              |=======================                                               |  33%  |                                                                              |=======================                                               |  34%  |                                                                              |========================                                              |  34%  |                                                                              |========================                                              |  35%  |                                                                              |=========================                                             |  35%  |                                                                              |=========================                                             |  36%  |                                                                              |==========================                                            |  37%  |                                                                              |==========================                                            |  38%  |                                                                              |===========================                                           |  38%  |                                                                              |===========================                                           |  39%  |                                                                              |============================                                          |  39%  |                                                                              |============================                                          |  40%  |                                                                              |============================                                          |  41%  |                                                                              |=============================                                         |  41%  |                                                                              |=============================                                         |  42%  |                                                                              |==============================                                        |  42%  |                                                                              |==============================                                        |  43%  |                                                                              |===============================                                       |  44%  |                                                                              |===============================                                       |  45%  |                                                                              |================================                                      |  45%  |                                                                              |================================                                      |  46%  |                                                                              |=================================                                     |  47%  |                                                                              |=================================                                     |  48%  |                                                                              |==================================                                    |  48%  |                                                                              |==================================                                    |  49%  |                                                                              |===================================                                   |  49%  |                                                                              |===================================                                   |  50%  |                                                                              |====================================                                  |  51%  |                                                                              |====================================                                  |  52%  |                                                                              |=====================================                                 |  52%  |                                                                              |=====================================                                 |  53%  |                                                                              |======================================                                |  54%  |                                                                              |======================================                                |  55%  |                                                                              |=======================================                               |  55%  |                                                                              |=======================================                               |  56%  |                                                                              |========================================                              |  57%  |                                                                              |========================================                              |  58%  |                                                                              |=========================================                             |  58%  |                                                                              |=========================================                             |  59%  |                                                                              |==========================================                            |  59%  |                                                                              |==========================================                            |  60%  |                                                                              |===========================================                           |  61%  |                                                                              |===========================================                           |  62%  |                                                                              |============================================                          |  62%  |                                                                              |============================================                          |  63%  |                                                                              |=============================================                         |  64%  |                                                                              |=============================================                         |  65%  |                                                                              |==============================================                        |  65%  |                                                                              |==============================================                        |  66%  |                                                                              |===============================================                       |  67%  |                                                                              |===============================================                       |  68%  |                                                                              |================================================                      |  68%  |                                                                              |================================================                      |  69%  |                                                                              |=================================================                     |  70%  |                                                                              |==================================================                    |  71%  |                                                                              |==================================================                    |  72%  |                                                                              |===================================================                   |  72%  |                                                                              |===================================================                   |  73%  |                                                                              |===================================================                   |  74%  |                                                                              |====================================================                  |  74%  |                                                                              |====================================================                  |  75%  |                                                                              |=====================================================                 |  75%  |                                                                              |=====================================================                 |  76%  |                                                                              |======================================================                |  76%  |                                                                              |======================================================                |  77%  |                                                                              |======================================================                |  78%  |                                                                              |=======================================================               |  78%  |                                                                              |=======================================================               |  79%  |                                                                              |========================================================              |  80%  |                                                                              |========================================================              |  81%  |                                                                              |=========================================================             |  81%  |                                                                              |=========================================================             |  82%  |                                                                              |==========================================================            |  82%  |                                                                              |==========================================================            |  83%  |                                                                              |===========================================================           |  84%  |                                                                              |===========================================================           |  85%  |                                                                              |============================================================          |  85%  |                                                                              |============================================================          |  86%  |                                                                              |=============================================================         |  87%  |                                                                              |=============================================================         |  88%  |                                                                              |==============================================================        |  88%  |                                                                              |==============================================================        |  89%  |                                                                              |===============================================================       |  90%  |                                                                              |===============================================================       |  91%  |                                                                              |================================================================      |  91%  |                                                                              |================================================================      |  92%  |                                                                              |=================================================================     |  92%  |                                                                              |=================================================================     |  93%  |                                                                              |==================================================================    |  94%  |                                                                              |==================================================================    |  95%  |                                                                              |===================================================================   |  95%  |                                                                              |===================================================================   |  96%  |                                                                              |====================================================================  |  97%  |                                                                              |====================================================================  |  98%  |                                                                              |===================================================================== |  98%  |                                                                              |===================================================================== |  99%  |                                                                              |======================================================================|  99%  |                                                                              |======================================================================| 100%
states_of_interest = region_2 %>%
  filter(NAME %in% c("Ohio", "Missouri", "Wisconsin"))

states_lines <- states_of_interest %>% sf::st_cast("MULTILINESTRING")


tm_shape(region_2) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "white") +
  tm_shape(states_lines) +
  tm_lines(col="NAME", lwd=2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I found this to be the best solution as well. Another option would have been to just separate the states into their own sf object and manually create the legend, but that would be tedious! Thanks again!